# username , password and other parameters in sqlserver connection string

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce, connection-string, sql-server-express

I'm new to C# and .net and just worked with php and mysql.
to connect to sqlserver express (in visual studio 2010) with c# we should provide a connection string that has lots of formats i found on the web specially in [connectionstrings](http://connectionstrings.com).
for example in standard format :
    "Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;UserId=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"

what is username and password? where can i find them? are they "root" and "" like in php mysql or something else?

as mentioned , i have created a database named "db.sdf" in sqlserver express in visual studio 2012.

I'm really confused. please help.

Comment: `sdf` is a SQL Server Compact Edition database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your database extension is `SDF`,you are creating `SQL Server CE` (*Compact Edition*) database file. Use this connection string

```
Data Source=" + (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + "\\MyData.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;
```

OR

```
Data Source=MyData.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;
```

**[More on this link.](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005-ce)**

**UPDATE 1**

You need the `System.Data.SqlServerCe` namespace.

```
SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=\\Mobile\\Northwind.sdf;");
conn.Open();
.
.
.
conn.Close();
```

**From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceconnection%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):** 
**Namespace:** System.Data.SqlServerCe
**Assembly:** System.Data.SqlServerCe (in system.data.sqlserverce.dll)

Comment: not working . when i add `con.Open()` , the rest of code dose not execute , but also no errors. i don't know why

Comment: can you post your code?maybe you are using wrong dataprovider.

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    class First
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            //string connectionString = ConsoleApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=db.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;");

                // 2. Open the connection
                con.Open();


                Console.WriteLine("ok");
                Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

Comment: You need to have included the `System.Data.SqlServerCe` namespace (*not the System.Data.SqlClient*). It's in the `System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll`.

Comment: and then what instead of `SqlConnection` type for con object ?

Comment: `SqlCeConnection` connection object

Comment: and where should i add that assembly ? sorry , i'm really new to .net

Comment: this [*link*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb219485.aspx) has provided a great tutorial for creating application that uses `sqlce` database file. it will even teach you how to add the assembly file you need :)